# Change category tree output

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I try to generate a nice unordered list from a specific parent category ID with the following code:

```
<?php
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(6);
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();

    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
    {
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
        if($_category->getIsActive()) {
            echo '<ul><li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'">'.$_category->getName().'</a></li>';
            $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
            $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
            foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
            {
                $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';

                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Currently the output is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Brand 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Brand 2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Material 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Material 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

While it should be:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Brands</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Brand 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brand 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Materials</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Material 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Material 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(6);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

echo '<ul>';

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
    if($_category->getIsActive()) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
        $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
        if ($sub_subcats) {
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
            {
                $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';

                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
}

echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(6);
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();

    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
    {
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
        if($_category->getIsActive()) {
            echo '<ul><li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
            $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
            $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
            if ($sub_subcats) {
                echo "<ul>";
                foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
                {
                    $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                    if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                        echo '<li><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';

                    }
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
            echo '</li></ul>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Damn, you are first again.

Comment: @Tim. you had 17 minutes to answer. What more do you want? :)

Comment: Thanks Marius, but now still each subcat is wrapped in <ul></ul> tags. I answered my own question with the right code for my desired result.